# Trouble adjusting images inside Cards

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-grid

the thing I'm trying to do is fetch the countries data from an API and render all of them as cards on the page.

**I'm facing trouble adjusting the size of flags ***because all of them have difference sizes***.**

[image]

**I've applied `width: 100%;` to make them fit inside the card, and `overflow: hidden` to its parent card. But the height is not the same for which I tried to apply `min-height: 50%` that didn't completely do the job**-

[image]

See the Australia flag? It gets white bars on top & bottom while there's no `margin`, etc., to the image. Could you please tell me how I can make them the same size?

https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-countries-api-1ibwp?file=/src/index.js

Comment: a problem that you have is that the images are not the same size. We don't want to distort the images so the only thing I could think of is to make the images as background cover.

Comment: @CyrusZei I thought of that but since I'm fetching the data and mapping it to the component, I can't access the image-urls in sass. Setting the background for each data-item in the script would be messy, so I was looking for a simpler solution using just stylesheet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the images style:

`Object-fit: cover;`

Comment: aha `object-fit` is the property I never used before, but it did my job this time!